# Add Class in closure function argument PHP - Uncaught TypeError thrown

Tags: php, oop, error-handling, closures

I have 3 classes

```
<?php
namespace App;

class Address {

    private $houseNumber = '';
    private $street = '';
    protected $city = '';
    protected $county = '';
    public $postcode = '';
    public $country = '';
    private $contacts = [];

    public function setHouseNumber($provided_housenumber){
        $this->houseNumber = $provided_housenumber;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setStreet($provided_street){
        $this->street = $provided_street;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setPostCode($provided_postcode){
        $this->postcode = $provided_postcode;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setCounty($provided_county){
        $this->county = $provided_county;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setCountry($provided_country){
        $this->country = $provided_country;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Second class

```
<?php
namespace App;

 class Book {

    private $records = [];

    public function createAddress(Address $address) {
        $this->records[] = $address;
    }

}
```

And third class

```
<?php
namespace App;

class Contact {

    private $name = '';
    public $email = '';

    public function setName($provided_name){
        $this->name = $provided_name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setEmail($provided_mail){
        $this->email = $provided_mail;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Then in index file I'm calling Book method like this:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Contact;
use App\Book;
use App\Address;

# Create first contact
$contact = new Contact;
$contact->setName('Mr John Doe');
$contact->setEmail('john@doe.com');

# Add first contact to list of contacts
$contacts[] = $contact;

# Open new book
$book = new Book;

# Add first address with both contacts
$book->createAddress(function(Address $address) use ($contacts){ //<---- Here it throws Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App\Book::createAddress() must be an instance of App\Address, instance of Closure given
    $address->setHouseNumber('33');
    $address->setStreet('Example street')->setCity('Cambridge');
    $address->setPostCode('CBF MB5');
    $address->setCounty('Cambridgeshire');
    $address->setCountry('GB');

    foreach($contacts as $contact){
        $address->addContact($contact);
    }
});
```

So what I'm tiring to do in index file - in new instance of Book I'm executing method createAddress() by wrapping it all up in anonymous function (closure function).

Than in that function I set all variables and pass it to the Book. But somehow I can not call Class in closure function as argument -

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Book::createAddress() must be an instance of App\Address, instance
>   of Closure given

So I definitely am missing something fundamental here, can somebody guide me through?

Comment: Guide through what?

Comment: Why it is not accepting Address Class as anonymous function argument?

Comment: `createAddress` requires `Address` instance, you pass `Closure`. What's is __unclear__ here? `Closure` is __not__ instance of `Address`.

Comment: Either make your `createAddress()` _not_ require an `Address` object as parameter or don't use a closure but create a `new Address()` object and pass that as parameter

Comment: Yes that's it, Thanks, @kerbholz that was the thing! 
I removed Address from createAddress() and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function createAddress(Address $address) // look, it wants an address!
```

You try and pass a closure, which the class didn't ask for. So ditch the closure.

```
$address = new Address();
$address->setHouseNumber('33');
$address->setStreet('Example street')->setCity('Cambridge');
$address->setPostCode('CBF MB5');
$address->setCounty('Cambridgeshire');
$address->setCountry('GB');

foreach ($contacts as $contact){
    $address->addContact($contact);
}

$book->createAddress($address);
```